Why in Star Wars are cybernetics being used instead of limb regeneration?
In the Star Wars universe, notably in the original and prequel trilogy, when someone lost his limb(s), typically in a lightsaber duel, the missing limb was replaced with a cybernetic limb (e.g. Luke Skywalker, and of course Darth Vader). Many YouTube videos about Star Wars (e.g. Star Wars Theory) said that the cybernetic limbs caused Vader a lot of pain, especially when detaching and reattaching them for maintenance or replacement.
In later franchise work, an advanced biotechnology was introduced and some comic books (and Episode 9) depicted the cloning of human beings (e.g. Cylo in Darth Vader comics from 2015). If one can clone an entire person, one can also develop the technology to regrow a limb and transplant it instead of the missing one.
Why did Luke Skywalker and Darth Vader use cybernetic limbs instead of regenerative limbs created from their body (e.g. using stem cells and DNA)?
